# How to databind a repeater from stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, data-binding

I'm trying to databind my repeater but so far not having any luck.  Anyone think that can show me where I'm going wrong?  I have two functions at the moment by following some tutorials/examples but I was hoping to have just one... maybe not possible. Thanks!

HTML:

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td><asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="PhoneLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub BindData()

    Dim oCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim oReader As SqlDataReader

    Try
        oCommand = DataAccess.GetSQLCommand("People_Retrieve", CommandType.StoredProcedure, SourceServer.ConnectionLocal)
        oCommand.Connection.ChangeDatabase("MyDatabase")

        oCommand.CommandTimeout() = 9000
        oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()

        PeopleRepeater.DataSource = oReader
        PeopleRepeater.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandler.HandleError(ex)
    Finally
        oReader.Close()
        oReader = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub PeopleRepeater_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles PeopleRepeater.ItemDataBound

    Dim NameLabel As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("LabelName"), Label)
    NameLabel.Text = e.Item.DataItem("Name")

    Dim TitleLabel As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("TitleName"), Label)
    NameLabel.Text = e.Item.DataItem("Title")

    Dim PhoneLabel As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("PhoneName"), Label)
    NameLabel.Text = e.Item.DataItem("Phone")

    Dim EmailLabel As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("EmailName"), Label)
    NameLabel.Text = e.Item.DataItem("Email")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
Using adap As New SqlDataAdapter(oCommand)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adap.Fill(table)

    PeopleRepeater.DataSource = table
    PeopleRepeater.DataBind()
End Using
```

I don't see where you're opening the connection either, so you might need to add that:

```
oCommand.Connection.Open()
```

Comment: Working on a VB.NET conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps

1. Create the stored procedure named as 'SelectPersonalDetails'

   CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPersonalDetails

   -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

   @Email  SYSNAME

   ```
   AS

   BEGIN
   ```

   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- Insert statements for procedure here

   BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   BEGIN

   SELECT Name,Title,Phone,Email FROM PersonalDetails

   WHERE 
   Email = @Email

   END

   COMMIT TRANSACTION

   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH

   ```
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   DECLARE @ERR AS VARCHAR(500)
   SELECT @ERR = ERROR_MESSAGE()   
   RAISERROR(@ERR,16,1)

   RETURN
   ```

   END CATCH
       END
2. Create dataset in order to bind the data in the repeater.

   public DataSet Get_PersonaldetailbasedEmail()
       {

   ```
       try
       {
           DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
           SqlParameter[] oParam = new SqlParameter[1];

           oParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Email", _sEmail);


           oDS = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(DataConnectionString,          CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SelectPersonalDetails", oParam);
           return oDS;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           ErrorMessage = e.Message;
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

Note: (i) SelectPersonalDetails is the stored procedure name

```
  (ii) In order to select unique record from the table i have used emailid 

  (iii) I have assume the table name as PersonalDetails.
```

1. Create a user control page something like Personeldetails.ascx

   /li>
         /li>
         /li>
         /li>

Note above i have the html code for repeater but i don't know how to work around in this editor. anyways repeater id is same as your repeater and label ids are same as your label id.

1. Databind

   Create a function to bind the data

   public void FillArray(ArrayList alist)
       {
           ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

   ```
       foreach (Object objRow in alist)
       {
           string sTitle = ((DataRow)objRow)["Title"].ToString();
           string sName = ((DataRow)objRow)["Name"].ToString();
           string sPhone = ((DataRow)objRow)["Phone"].ToString();
          string sMail = ((DataRow)objRow)["Mail"].ToString();        

           al.Add(new string[]{ sTitle,sName,sPhone,sMail});


       }
       PeopleRepeater.DataSource = al;
       PeopleRepeater.DataBind();


   }
   ```
2. Now called Item databound

   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
           {
               string[] itemArray = ((string[])e.Item.DataItem);

   ```
           Label myTitle = (Lable)e.Item.FindControl("TitleLabel");
           Label myName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("NameLabel");
           Label myPhone = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("PhoneLabel");
           Label myEmail = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("EmailLabel");

           myTitle.Text = itemArray[0];
           myName.Text = itemArray[1];
           myPhone.Text = itemArray[2];
           myEmail.Text = itemArray[3];




       }
   ```

If you find the answer useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know....

Comment: I think this is a little too localized. I would try to cut it down to only what OP asked for.

Comment: This question is tagged VB.NET too.